# Как повесить показ хинтов на jQuery-компонент Chosen?

Tags: jquery, плагин, события

Пытаюсь переделать элемент `select` в jQuery-компонент [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Не могу понять как подвесить на Chosen показ всплывающих подсказок. На `select` и другие элементы в форме скриптами получилось повесить обработчики, а вот как то же самое сделать для Chosen пока не представляю, поскольку этот элемент создается на лету и я не могу прописать ему вручную даже `id`. подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли какие-то варианты?

Answer (score 1):

А чем JQuery UI не подходит? В нём есть Tooltip который выдаёт содержимое 'title' в мини модалах, только здесь почемуто не запускается. Посмотри здеcь http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      collapsible: true
    });
 
    $( "#files" ).selectmenu();
  $( document ).tooltip();
 
    $( "#number" )
      .selectmenu()
      .selectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "overflow" );
  });
```

```css
fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }
    select {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <div class="demo">
 
<form action="#">
 
  <fieldset>
    <label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
    <select name="speed" id="speed">
      <option>Slower</option>
      <option>Slow</option>
      <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
      <option>Fast</option>
      <option>Faster</option>
    </select>
 
    <label for="files">Select a file</label>
    <select name="files" id="files">
      <optgroup label="Scripts">
        <option value="jquery">jQuery.js</option>
        <option value="jqueryui">ui.jQuery.js</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Other files">
        <option value="somefile">Some unknown file</option>
        <option value="someotherfile">Some other file with a very long option text</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
 
    <label for="number">Select a number</label>
    <select name="number" id="number" title="one">
      <option title="one">1</option>
      <option selected="selected">2</option>
      <option title="3">3</option>
      <option title="4">4</option>
      <option title="5">5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>13</option>
      <option>14</option>
      <option>15</option>
      <option>16</option>
      <option>17</option>
      <option>18</option>
      <option>19</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
 
</form>
 
</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```